# Page Speed Insights Failure

Tags: pagespeed-insights

When I enter the website URL that I would like to analyze & click "analyze", the results do not pull through and I get a failed status. I have never encountered this issue and not sure what I can do to be able to run the analysis successfully.

I entered the URL & was expecting a successful analysis to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

- your CDN or a server's firewall (WAF) blocked such an automated test.
- it's a website with too many (broken?) JS, causing the test to fail.

This could be confirmed by trying to test other sites and see if analysis is still failing.